# Should I edit external image links by reuploading on Imgur?

Tags: discussion, images, external-links

Take as an example this question: [Mahapps Metro: Show non-modal auto-closing message dialog at the bottom of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26237436/1928529).

It contains a link to tumblr.com. I couldn't find how long Tumblr keeps images online. Is it acceptable/encouraged to replace references to an external image with an image on the Stack Exchange [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) account? Are there any legal/copyright issues in doing this?

Comment: +1 for turning this into a [meta-tag:feature-request] for linked/embedded images to be automatically re-hosted as explained in [Ben's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273040/1331430).

Comment: Somewhat related: [Disallow new embedded images from hosts other than the SE imgur account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231613/167646)

Comment: Related: [Pulling old hotlinked images into imgur account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161921/135695)

Comment: It annoyed me *(sorry)* so I've linked the actually [image url](http://36.media.tumblr.com/d93b51078b1d63a7bc2535f0a241efcc/tumblr_mw69pjkiHd1sigwgoo1_1280.png) (so the image shows) and hyperlinked it so it points to the [tumbler url](http://sloppyui.tumblr.com/image/68176091078).

Comment: I'm not sure about the T&C of Tumblr, but content posted there isn't content posted here. Even if it's linked and displayed from a page on SO, I see no reason why it would fall under SO's CC licence.
Hence, in general, no, don't re-host what you find somewhere else on Imgur, simply because you might not be allowed to do so. Practically, even if the licence where it is published allows that material to be redistributed, it can be difficult to keep a track of the origin and acknowledge the authors and copyright holders appropriately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you shouldn't.  ("You" meaning all users who have not earned [unsupervised edit privilege at 2k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

If the community and powers-that-be decide it would be appropriate to do, SE developers can script it much more efficiently than your edit suggestions (which btw involve reviewers).  And they can submit updates directly to the database without increasing the revision count or bumping questions to the front page.

You should fix your own questions to host images in a persistent location, but no one else's.

(I would make the same argument for links to code on ideone, which does have a policy about how long they keep content, but does not follow that policy)

---

I also want to point out a severe problem with off-site URLs, especially image URLs, and the suggested edit queue.  Namely, that the linked-to content can be changed after the edit has been approved.

The last thing we want is a 1-rep user "rehosting" a bunch of images in other people's questions and answers, then a month down the line, replacing them all with spam (or even more offensive images).

If you come across image URLs in the suggested edit review queue, immediately hit Reject!  No matter how good the rest of the edit or what the current content of the image is, accepting an edit that pulls in off-site content is giving the untrusted editor the ability to change that post in the future without review.

Comment: What if I am already preforming another edit at the same time?  Would it be worth it to do it then?

Comment: @Pokechu22: The image host should be left up to the post author, until such time as the decision is made to end all off-site image tags, in which case the process will be automated.

Comment: Ok, then what about cases where the image was provided as a link to an off-site image (EG `http://example.com/some/long/url/to/some/image.png`?  Should we embed that one, or should it be rehosted?  (I'd edit it to insert the image directly either way)

Comment: @Pokechu22: You shouldn't do either.  Image URL changes shouldn't go through the suggested edits queue.  Someone with high enough rep should do it, with rehosting, and then they are taking responsibility for the image content.

Comment: If I'm making another edit at the same time, should I do it?  Because that seems like an easy thing to fix that yields a major improvement, especially if I am fixing typos as well.

Comment: @Pokechu22: You're under 2k rep, so no.  And the reason is that is isn't "a major improvement", it actually introduces a security vulnerability.  Whoever controls the image hosting (in the case of imgur, it's the person who uploaded the image) can change that image at any time.

Comment: I'm not referring to reuploading externally.  If you select the insert picture option, and choose "From the web", it actually reuploads it automatically (to stack.imgur.com).

Comment: Can images hosted at the stack subdomain actually be altered down the line? How would you even access them?

Comment: @AirThomas: I know it's possible on public imgur, so I don't want to make a bet that there's no mechanism on stack.imgur.com.  Besides, it's hard enough to train edit reviewers to reject image URL changes, without some URLs being ok and some not.  (And then we can start into [URLs that look like they are hosted on stack.imgur.com, but are not](http://stack.imgur.com@example.com))  The only sane thing to do is **reject all suggested edits that add or change image URLs**

Comment: The way you do it on the public imgur is via an associated user account. I don't know if it's possible to link those accounts to the stack subdomain. Regardless of the discussion about edits, that seems like something that should be blocked.

Comment: Ben, the stack imgur is a commercial installation. You have no control over the image uploaded there because it's uploaded using the stack imgur account. In theory, the stack exchange staff does, but i wouldn't worry about them maliciously editing the image you've uploaded.

Comment: @corsiKa: Is that stated somewhere ("image re-upload/replacement is disabled")?  Or you're just assuming that it is because how to do it is not apparent?  And that still doesn't address the issue of whether reviewers are better at discriminating `stack.imgur.com` URLs in suggested edits than they are in phishing emails.

Comment: @corsiKa: But please don't misinterpret my "do not suggest edits changing image URLs, and reject them if seen in review" as "2k users should never change image URLs".  I'm not worried about image changes made by people with unrestricted edit privileges, whether those are stack exchange staff or merely 2k+ users.  Site policy is that 2k users are trusted to make edits to posts without oversight; there's not a problem if they can also change images without oversight.

Comment: @BenVoigt It should be about as easy to make that image URL changes auto-reject as it would be to auto-re-upload an image.  So by the same argument in the second paragraph of the answer, it shouldn't be an "always reject", either.

Comment: @BenVoigt The two halves of your answer seem to be at odds with each other anyway.  On the one hand, you're saying "don't replace externally-hosted images with SE-uploaded images", but on the other you're saying "don't use externally-hosted images because they can be changed later down the line".  If stack-hosting the images is the protection against later change of the image at a URL, when that should be a good change that under-2ks should make.

Comment: @Izkata: It's too difficult for reviewers to tell whether the new image URL is on a safe site, as I've explained in comments.  If images are going to be rehosted, it should be done by those who have earned the community's trust, or even better yet, automated.

Answer (score 10):

If having the image as part of the post would constitute an improvement, then yes, you should. Consider it similar to bringing in the content from any external link.

However, I would recommend only doing this if you're fixing something else in the post.

Comment: Changing an image URL is not something that reviewers should be approving, unless the old URL is actually a broken link.  For 2k users whose edits bypass the queue, I agree, it's ok to roll that in with another edit.

Comment: @BenVoigt There's a difference between rehosting somewhere else, and rehosting on SE's image site.

Comment: I don't trust reviewers to tell the difference.  Neither would you, if think about URL obfuscation techniques made popular in phishing emails.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you absolutely should. Other embedded image links tend to:

- not work over HTTPS (although this isn’t the case for Tumblr)
- leak information to the sites hosting them (why is this still allowed?)
- break

If the images aren’t subject to the same license as the post, they shouldn’t be part of it.

Comment: Your last statement is very problematic if you consider images referenced via markup to be "part of the post".  We clearly are not going to ban links to offsite media and documentation under other licenses, and editors have been adding markup for image links for years.  That train has already left the station, we have image markup for a lot of content that has not been licensed under CC BY-SA.  You can't simply claim ownership of all of it.

Comment: They're also not resized server-side; I've a few times had to replace images on the order of 20,000 by 20,000 pixels with a stack-hosted one (and then just linked to the full-size).  (This was on SciFi.SE, so it's a bit of an outlier, but still.)

Comment: This is terrible advice. As an editor, you have virtually no way of knowing the licence under which the image was initially posted."*If the images aren’t subject to the same license as the post, they shouldn’t be part of it.*": maybe they shouldn't, but sometimes they will be, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bruno: So, when in doubt, don’t, or make it not embedded. The fact is, unofficial embedded images should be blocked entirely, and should have been from the start; we would have never had any of the many problems.

Comment: Linking to something isn't necessarily bad: SE is not hosting the content and doesn't take responsibility for doing so. It's just SE's obsession with being self-contained that conflicts with that, and copying the content elsewhere opens a different kind of legal problems.

Comment: @Bruno: I didn’t say that linking to something external was bad. Embedding it is bad.