# Suggested edits that attempt to replace an Imgur image with an edited one

Tags: support, suggested-edits, images

I've seen it more than two times, of users changing an Imgur link with what seems to be an almost identical image (if there is an alteration, it's imperceptible). Here are two examples among others:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14755456 by [luke-melaia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3376221/luke-melaia)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14690172 by [pramod-gharu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536063/pramod-gharu)

Is there an ownership issue at editing images hosted on Imgur?

Should edits like that be accepted or rejected?

Comment: Personally, I would be suspicious of someone who has changed the image in a inconceivable way and would probably vote to reject edit

Answer (score 16):

No there isn't any ownership issue changing one `i.stack.imgur.com` URL to another. No special rights are granted to the person that originally uploaded it.

Probably they just aren't very proficient with the editor yet and instead of just editing the markdown directly they used the image button on the toolbar to make their changes and it ended up reuploading an image already hosted there.

You should not be rejecting edits on this basis with reasons such as "attempting to re-appropriate the image" and "replacing author image with a different owner".

Just ignore this and evaluate the rest of the edit. If the rest of the edit is good and it bothers you that much you can even select the "improve" option and restore the original URL but it makes no practical difference which is used if there is no perceptible differences between the images and both are hosted at `i.stack.imgur.com`.

Comment: Sounds to contradict http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273040/1033581

Comment: @Cœur no there's no contradiction. That is talking about changing off site images to on site images and vice versa. In the cases you are asking about the on site image is just replaced by an other on site image making no difference to anything.

Comment: Seems to me that `accepting an edit that pulls in off-site content is giving the untrusted editor the ability to change that post in the future without review.` from [that other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273040/1033581) still holds.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels - `i.stack.imgur.com` is the standard place for all image uploads using the image upload facility in the toolbar. This is not regarded as "off site". The person uploading it has no special privileges that would allow them to edit the image to something else later.

Comment: ah right. Ofcourse.